# gdb throw error "Error creating process XXXXXX (error 5)."

Tags: gdb, access-denied, createprocess

[image]
I know the error 5 mean to "Access Denied".(Because the number 5 is threw by the CreateProcess function in windows API.)

The last time I run into this problem, I have no way to solve it. Just over a period of time, the problem inexplicably disappeared.

The file P1010.exe in the figure can be deleted, and can be generated by build again. I don't know why it will throw the "Access Denied" error.Thanks in advance.